# User input prompt with countdown

Tags: r

In an interactive `R` session, what's a good way to implement a user input prompt with a countdown running in the background? For example, I'd like the following fictive `R` code to return `NA` if the user doesn't respond within 10 seconds:

```
readline("Continue? (Y/n): ", timer=10)
```

Comment: In potential this is an interesting question. Maybe you can elaborate a bit on what you are trying to achieve, show some context (i.e. code in which this is or should be embedded) and what you have already tried.

Comment: I guess you have to go the Tcl/Tk way - check out some [recipes](http://www.sciviews.org/recipes/tcltk/toc/).